# Determining if a Java app is malware

Tags: java, security, malware

I am curious about what automatic methods may be used to determine if a Java app running on a Windows or PC is malware. (I don't really even know what exploits are available to such an app. Is there someplace I can learn about the risks?) If I have the source code, are there specific packages or classes that could be used more harmfully than others? Perhaps they could suggest malware?

**Update**: Thanks for the replies. I was interested in knowing if this would be possible, and it basically sounds totally infeasible. Good to know.

Comment: do you have a working definition of malware? something that changes the local system? registry? files on disk? something that 'steals' information and sends it somewhere else? keyboard sniffing?  you can do alot that may count as either good or bad depending on your perspective.

Comment: You can check if Evil Bit has been set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's not even possible to automatically determine [whether a program terminates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), I don't think you'll get much leverage in automatically determining whether an app does "naughty stuff".

Part of the problem of course is defining what constitutes malware, but the majority is simply that deducing proofs about the behaviour of other programs is surprisingly difficult/impossible.  You may have some luck spotting particular patterns, but on the whole you can't be confident (and I suspect it's provably impossible) that you've caught all possible attack vectors.

And in the general sphere, catching 95% of vectors isn't really worthwhile when the attackers simply concentrate on the remaining 5%.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking about the sandboxing techniques around which java was originally developed (not the halting problem)

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's always the fundamental philosophical question: what is a malware? It's code that was intended to do damage, or at least code that doesn't do what it claims to. How do you plan to judge intent based on libraries it uses?

Having said that, if you at least roughly know what the program is supposed to do, you can indeed find suspicious packages, things the program wouldn't normally need to access. Like network connections when the program is meant to run as a desktop app. But then the network connection could just be part of an autoupdate feature. (Is autoupdate itself a malware? Sometimes it feels like it is.)

Another indicator is if a program that ostensibly doesn't need any special privileges, refuses to run in a sandbox. And the biggest threat is if it tries to load a native library when it shouldn't need one.

But all these only make sense if you know what the code is supposed to do. An antivirus package might use very similar techniques to viruses, the only difference is what's on the label.

Comment: AV-software distributes itself secretly? Which?

Comment: And how do you know, what a native library contains, and why the program needs it? Btw.: I have dozens of desktop programs which need net-access, like chats, VOIP, browser, email-client, audio-CD-programs, ...

Comment: @user unknown If you had read and understood my answer before you commented on it, you wouldn't look such a fool now.

Comment: Ok, I only addressed the network question. And your comparing of AV-software with viruses. Does it need to hide from the user? What is the similar technique? If you have a native library and don't have the source, or some debugging or reverse-engineering tools, what can you conclude from the fact of the native library? If the program is, for example, an office suite, an email client, an interactive Sudoku game, an editor? What? Native library and malware are orthogonal concepts. You can have one without the other, and vice versa.

Comment: @user unknown Similar techniques used by viruses/AV software include: hijacking network traffic, hijacking disk I/O, automatically refreshing itself from a remote server. I still don't think you understood what I said: if you've got say a desktop Java game of Solitaire and it loads a custom native library, that's a bit suspicious, isn't it? Considering that a Solitaire game doesn't need anything Java doesn't have. Of course if you know that a program is supposed to connect to the netwrok, then it connecting to the network isn't suspicious. I think I made all that quite clear in my answer.

Comment: @user unknown All this only serves to raise a strong suspicion, as I quite clearly pointed out in my answer. I really don't see what you find so hard to understand in it.

Comment: You made yourself clear, that it might be for update purpose. That's the moment the network argument died. AV-software: There I give in, you make some points. However - Disk-I/O, Networktraffic themselve aren't suspicious? A Solitaire game can use a native lib for every purpose. Maybe the programmer knows it, and liked to reuse it, so he needn't learn something new. Maybe he thought it is more performant, maybe he just wanted to test it out. It could include a clever or clever advertised shuffle algorithm. Nothing you couldn't do in Java, but that's not the point. The program is there as is.

Comment: Maybe you don't understand the statistics. You have 1000 Java programs, and 950 of them use disk I/O. 200 access the network. 50 use native libs. 3 of them are malware, 1 is using disk-io, one is using the network, and one is using a native lib. You investigate all programs, because every one is doing one of the 3 things, but your criteria isn't helpful. You have too much false positives: harmless programs, which raise suspicion. Your ockham-razor is a spoon.

Comment: @user unknown I can't help feeling a bit confused now. First you say "the network argument died" then in the very next sentence you ask if network traffic itself isn't suspicious. Well, if you don't expect it and can't see any reason for it, it is suspicious. If you find a plausible explanation for it, it ceases to be. That's pretty much the definition of suspicion. However I would be very wary with a developer who includes a native library "because he knows it" or "to test it out". Although not for security reasons.

Comment: @user unknown And your statistics are from? Regardless of where you got them from, you still fail to understand the basic idea: if the program is doing something that you don't expect, it's suspicious. A chat client is expected to connect to the network but is rarely expected to do disk I/O. Other programs are the other way around. It's not what the program does, but how it relates to your expectations and knowledge of what it is supposed to do that matters. I mean, do I really have to spell it out for you?

Comment: How do you know the motives of the programmer? You don't know. I'm sorry for the question mark at 'aren't suspicious?' - typing error. Of course network traffic is every day life. If you know how the program works in detail, you know it already. A malware writer would find a reason for his program to use the net, the disk, whatever his target is, to cover his target. "Write the highscore to the registry as administrator OK? Reilly OK?."

Comment: @user unknown You demonstrated exactly what I mean.

Comment: @biziclop: Of course, chat programs write to disk. They save channel- and server-settings, favorite GUI layout, window position and size, avatar, friends, logs, ... . I don't know what chat-client you use. You believe that you have a clear expectation not only what, but how your program reaches its goal. Well - why don't you write it yourself. Did you ever watch a program challenge and only saw similar solutions? Other people find different solutions. If the program does IO for good reasons, you don't know that it is malware. Most programs do IO for good reasons. But they still might be evil.

Comment: @user unknown Of course I have a clear expectation, why would you use a program you don't know the purpose of? And the purpose pretty much dictates the solution. If there's nothing to write to disk, there's nothing to write to disk. There are no ifs and buts. If a program that needs no native libraries to perform its task does so, that's suspicious, whatever made up counterexamples you come up with. If an ordinary program refuses to run in restricted mode, it's suspicious. Suspicious doesn't mean guilty, it's just that: suspicious. Malware is a subjective category at the end of the day.

Comment: I make a last attempt. Only programs which write to disk or do network traffic or use native libs are suspicious. I can agree on that to some degree. Well, and that is more than 90% of all programs I guess. You could as well state, that only programs which use int and String are suspicious. It's senseless.

Comment: @user unknown That's why the answer in practice is no, there's no way to determine what's malware by looking at the libraries it uses. Which, correct me if I'm wrong is exactly what I said in my answer. I could've left it at that, but I chose to elaborate over what you may try and why these methods still don't work very well. Then you came along and said exactly the same thing, but pretending for some reason to be disagreeing with me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general outline for how you can bound the possible actions your java application can take.  Basically you are testing to see if the java application is 'inert' (can't take harmful actions) and thus it probably not mallware.

This won't necessarily tell you mallware or not, as others have pointed out.  The app could still do annoying things like pop-up windows.  Perhaps the best indication, is to see if the application is digitally signed by an author you trust; if not -- be afraid.

You can disassemble the class files to determine which Java APIs the application uses; you are looking for points where the java app uses the OS.  Since java uses a virtual machine, there are well defined points where a java application could take potentially harmful actions -- these are the 'gateways' to various OS calls (for example opening a socket or reading a file).

Its difficult to enumerate all the APIs, different functions which execute the same OS action should require the same [Permission](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/package-summary.html).  But java's docs don't provide an exhaustive list.

- Does the java app use any native libraries -- if so its a big red flag.

  The JVM does not offer the ability to run arbitrary code, or use native system APIs; in particular it does not offer the ability to modify the registry (a typical action of PC mallware).  The only way a java application can do this is via native libraries.  Typically there is no need for a normal application written in java to use native code (unless it needs to use devices).

  Check for System.loadLibrary() or System.load() or Runtime.loadLibrary() or Runtime.load().  This is how the VM loads native libraries.
- Does it use the network or file system?

  Look for use of java.io, java.net.
- Does it make system calls (via Runtime.exec())

  You can check for the use of java.lang.Runtime.exec() or ProcessBuilder.exec().
- Does it try to control the keyboard / mouse?

You could also run the application in a restricted policy JVM (the instructions/tools for doing this are not as simple as they should be) and see what fails (see [Oracle's security tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour2/step2.html)) -- note that disassembly is the only way to be sure, just because the app doesn't do anything harmful once, doesn't mean it won't in the future.

This definitely is not easy, and I was surprised to find how many places one needs to look at (for example several java functions load native libraries, not just one).

Comment: Why are native libraries a big, red flag? For which kind of task do I need native libs, which couldn't be performed with standard java libs? What's wrong with using files or network? Why is calling Runtime.exec suspicious? Summa summarum your suggestion is: If your program can't do anything, it can't do harmful things. But that's trivial.

Comment: The point is to start where the application could take harmful actions and work backwards.  Using native libraries changes it from a java application to an arbitrary application.  I prefer this answer to 'give up'.

Comment: Harmful actions differ from welcomed actions not in what they do, but whether the user wants it to be done. All sorts of programs Open, modify and delete files, a lot of programs access the registry (on systems, where a registry exists, which is a file, after all) and accessing the net might be harmful or not. Changing a few pixels on the screen can be harmful in the right moment. You can't find out about it at looking at the libraries used - big, red flags is nothing but noise.

Comment: What color flag would you prefer?